# magento connect manager giving "no action selected" error every time i try to upgrade a module

Tags: javascript, php, magento, e-commerce

i'm trying to upgrade some modules in my magento website.
Every time i go to magento connect manager and i check for updates i get bunch of new version for my modules, now when i choose to upgrade one or multiple of these modules and i click commit it gives me a message" no action selected" .

i have no clue what's going on here !
can anyone help me please on this issue.

i just moved host to a new host and i had couple problem, i solved some of them and still have this one and another one.

Regards

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox, but i even tried chrome and it's the same, i don't think this is a browser issue. thanks

Comment: How did you upgrade this version 1.9.1?  You might upgrade magento connect manager.

Comment: sorry the version is 1.9.0.1 actually

Answer (score 0):

I also had this `no action selected` error when updating Magento using the Magento Connect Manager / Downloader.

And I needed to re-enter my admin user name and password when checking for updates, after receiving the `Please re-enter your Magento Administration Credentials. Only administrators with full permissions will be able to log in.` notice in the downloader section.

It appeared that I had set my Firefox browser to [Do Not Track](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/dnt/) and [Never remember history](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/settings-privacy-browsing-history-do-not-track#w_never-remember-history). After changing those settings I was able to use the Magento Connect Manager without the `no action selected` error.

So I guess this must be an issue with cookies or the fact that your browser does not remember which updates you have selected from the dropdown options in the actions column once you hit the `Commit Changes` button

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I was not able to install any link from connect, upload anything or even update or uninstall.

Turns out it came from my .htaccess

I wouldn't be able to say what exactly because I just switched back to my .htaccess backup - so I don't know what caused the problem, but if you're running in the same problem, try restoring the original .htaccess and making your changes 1 by 1